# Proof completion: if $Y$ is a closed term in strong nf, then $Yx$ weakly reduces to a strong nf $Z$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, computer-science, combinatory-logic

I am self-studying Hindley & Seldin's *Lambda-Calculus and Combinators*. I would appreciate some help with filling in a final detail for a proof for the following statement regarding combinatory logic:

**Claim.** *If a closed term $Y$ is in strong nf, then $Yx$ weakly reduces to a strong nf $Z$.*

Weak reduction (notation: $\rhd_w$) is defined as usual: $X \rhd_w Y$ *iff* there exists a (possibly empty) series of $\mathsf{I}, \mathsf{K}, \mathsf{S}$ contractions from $X$ to $Y$. For completeness, the single contractions are as follows:

- $\mathsf{I}x \rhd_{1w} x$
- $\mathsf{K}xy \rhd_{1w} x$
- $\mathsf{S}xyz \rhd_{1w} xz(yz)$

The book states that the claim can be proven by induction on the following definition:

**Definition 1. (Strong normal forms)**

1. All atoms other than $\mathsf{I}$, $\mathsf{K}$ and $\mathsf{S}$ are in strong normal form;
2. if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are in strong normal form and $a$ is any atom $\not \equiv \mathsf{I}, \mathsf{K}, \mathsf{S}$, then $aX_1\ldots X_n$ is in strong normal form;
3. if $X$ is in strong nf, then so is $[x].X$.

Here, $[x]$ is the pseudoabstractor (also denoted by $\lambda^*$ in other literature), defined as follows:

**Definition 2. (Abstraction)** For every CL-term $M$ and every variable $x$, a CL-term called $[x].M$ is defined by induction on $M$, thus:

1. $[x].M \equiv \mathsf{K}M$ $\hspace{29.8mm}$if $x \not\in FV(M)$
2. $[x].x \equiv \mathsf{I}$
3. $[x].Ux \equiv U$ $\hspace{33mm}$if $x \not\in FV(U)$
4. $[x].UV \equiv \mathsf{S}([x].U)([x].V)$ $\hspace{6mm}$if neither (1) nor (3) applies

Note that $\equiv$ denotes syntactical equivalence.

This is what I have so far:

*Proof.* Assume that the closed term $Y$ is in strong nf. The cases are as follows according to Def. 1.

1. $Y \equiv a$ (with $a$ some variable). Then $Yx \equiv ax \rhd_{w} ax$. By Def. 1.1, $x$ is in strong nf. By Def 1.2, and the preceding fact, $ax$ is in strong nf.
2. $Y \equiv aX_1...X_n$ with $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ in strong nf. Then $Yx \equiv aX_1...X_nx \rhd_{w} aX_1...X_n x$. Since $X_1, \ldots, X_n, x$ are all in strong nf, so is $aX_1\ldots X_nx$ by Def 1.2.
3. $Y \equiv [x].X$ with $X$ in strong nf. Then the cases must be distinguished according to Def. 2.

   a. $x \not\in FV(X)$. Then $Yx \equiv \mathsf{K}Xx \rhd_{w} X$. $X$ is in strong nf by hypothesis.

   b. $X \equiv x$. Then $Yx \equiv \mathsf{I}x \rhd_{w} x$. $x$ is in strong nf by Def 1.1.

   c. $X \equiv Ux$ with $x \not\in FV(U)$. Then $Yx \equiv ([x].Ux)x \equiv Ux \equiv X \rhd_w X$. $X$ is in strong nf by hypothesis.

   **Now for the final case, which gives me trouble**:

   d. $X \equiv UV$ with $x \in FV(UV)$ and $V \not\equiv x$. Then $$Yx \equiv \mathsf{S}([x].U)([x].V)x \rhd_{w} ([x].U)x(([x].V)x)$$By the IH, both $([x].U)x$ and  $([x].V)x$ weakly reduce to strong nfs $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

   **Question**: Should I now argue that $Z_1Z_2$ *weakly reduces to* a strong normal form, or that $Z_1Z_2$ *is* a strong normal form? If the former, how do I properly complete this argument without falling into the trap of infinite regress?

Let me know if you require additional information.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that for every **strong nf** $X$ the expression $([y]X)x$ weakly reduce to a **strong nf** I think you should use induction over definition of **strong nf** not over *abstraction*.

To prove this we procede by induction over definition of **strong nf**:

- if $X \equiv y$ then by definition $[y]X=[y]y=I$ and so $([y]X)x=x$ which is a **strong nf**;
- if $X \equiv a$ with $a$ an atom different than $S$, $I$, $K$ and $y$ then $[y]X=KX$ and so $([y]X)x=X$ which is **strong nf** by hypothesis;
- if $X \equiv a X_1 \dots X_n$ with $a$ being atom different by $S$, $I$ and $K$ and the $X_i$ being all **strong nf** then by definition of abstraction we have that $[y]X=[y]aX_1\dots X_{n-1}X_n\equiv S([y]aX_1\dots X_{n-1})([y]X_n)$ and so $([y]X)x \equiv ([y]aX_1 \dots X_{n-1})x(([y]X_n)x)$ which is equal (this can be easily proved by induction on the number $n$ of terms applied to $a$) to 
  $$[([y]a)x][([y]X_1)x][([y]X_2)x]\dots[([y]X_n)[x]]$$
  since all $X_i$ a **strong nf** by inductive hypothesis each $([y]X_i)x\rhd_w Z_i$ and similarily $([y]a)x \rhd_w A$ where the $Z_i$ are **strong nf** while $A$ is either $x$ (if $a\equiv y$) or $a$ (so $A$ is an atom), so by applying the substitution lemma 
  $$([y]X)x\equiv [([y]a)x][([y]X_1)x]\dots[([y]X_n)x] \rhd_w AZ_1\dots Z_n$$

where $AZ_1 \dots Z_n$ is a **strong nf** since all the $Z_i$ are **Strong nf** and $A$ is an atom.

This proves the point 3 and so conclude your proof.

Comment: Would this not result in an infinite regress? To me it seems I would have to cover case 3 (d) again for $Z_1$. I will reason analogously and conclude that $Z_1 \rhd_w (Z_3Z_4)$ with both $Z_3$ and $Z_4$ in strong normal form.

Comment: @RoyO. I'm probably a little rusty, but isn't it true that a reduction of a term has complexity less than the starting term?

Comment: If you mean weak reduction, then not necessarily. For example, the $\lambda$-term $X \equiv \lambda x.xxx$ has a CL equivalent $X_{CL} \equiv [x].xxx$, and $X_{CL}X_{CL} \rhd_w X_{CL}X_{CL}X_{CL} \rhd_w \ldots$. If you mean eliminating bound variables from a $[x]$-term, then the complexity technically stays the same (since all terms are syntactically identical), but you *are* guaranteed to eliminate all variables eventually. I have a feeling this fact can be used in the proof, but I am not sure how to properly argue. (Thanks for your help so far.)

Comment: @RoyO. After a deep reading of the book you cited above I think I've finally found a solution to your problem, take a look and let me know if it's not clear :)

Comment: Two things are unclear to me. First, you write $[y].aX1…X_{n−1}X_n≡S([y].aX_1…X_{n−1})([y].X_n)$. But this seems to assume that (1) and (3) of Def. 2 do not apply. If this is a mistake on your part, however, and not a misunderstanding on mine, then I see how it can be easily remedied, so it is not very problematic to me. Second, it does not seem exhaustive. For example, $[xyz].xyz \equiv \mathsf{S}$. So in part you need to prove that $([x].\mathsf{S})x$ weak reduces to a strong nf (which is easy for this particular *case*), but this is not covered by your cases...

Comment: ...since these cases all assume a leading atom $\not \equiv \mathsf{I}, \mathsf{K}, \mathsf{S}$. From the definition it is not very obvious what kind of terms will result from the use of pseudoabstraction, so that's why I thought the case distinction for Def. 2 was necessary in my original proof. Again, thanks for your efforts, and let me know if I seem to misunderstand something.